# How do you call a maven project from a java project

Tags: maven, intellij-idea, javafx, pdf-generation

I have a javafx program that calculates results from user data, I want to generate a PDF file from the data I have calculated. I know that I need to use iText but I dont know how to link the two or an instruction in my javafx project that can execute the maven project that needs to be used to be able to generate a PDF file. Im using IntelliJ as my IDE.

Comment: This question is a bit confusing. You probably should build your JavaFX program with Maven and declare iText as a dependency.

Comment: maven is basically just a build system, as far as you're concerned. You don't need to "call a maven project" from your code, you just need to call functions inside the iText JARs (and figure out how to add the iText JARs to your classpath). JF Meier's suggestion to use maven for your project and declare iText as a dependency is one way to do that. I think if you did a little reading on maven and how to use external libraries in Java you would be in a better position to solve your problem (and to ask a better-formed question)

Comment: If you aren't ready to configure Maven for this task, get the iText jar file and add it to your IntelliJ project as Eidolon108 suggested.  Once it's part of your project, you'll be able to call the iText functions and use iText sample code to create the PDF.